# FATAL: out of memory +postgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We are facing `FATAL:  out of memory` frequently in postgreSQL 9.6 database, we have 125 GB physical memory available on the DB Server and 8 GB has been allocated to shared_buffers.

Please provide inputs to tune any DB related parameters to avoid out of memory related issues.

Comment: Please add your settings influencing memory usage - like work_mem, maintenance_work_mem, max_connections, temp_buffers. Plus full error message - there are several types of "out of memory" problems.

Comment: Thanks for the update Jos, below are the configuration details and complete error message.

work_mem=5242kB
maintenance_work_mem=2G

Comment: Thanks for the update Jos, below are the configuration details and complete error message.

work_mem=5242kB
maintenance_work_mem=2G
max_connections=6000
temp_buffers=10MB

2018-01-13 02:06:21 ICT [2322]: [2-1] user=xxxx,db=xxxx,app=[unknown],client=xx.xx.xx.xx FATAL:  out of memory
2018-01-13 02:06:21 ICT [2322]: [3-1] user=xxxx,db=xxxx,app=[unknown],client=XX.XX.XX.XX DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 769536.

Comment: Thanks, since have huge max_connections here are some additional questions: 1) do you know average number of connections + top number of connections? 2) could you check your setting for shared mem and semaphors - command "ipcs -l" (param is "small L")? 3) Do you have swap?

Comment: most of the times we can see connections are hitting to 4500-5500(however  few times it has reached to 5900 and we have 3 databases).

Comment: [postgres@xxxxxxxx audit]$ ipcs -l

------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 32768
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 1000000
max seg size (kbytes) = 99614720
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 99614720
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 5256
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 100
semaphore max value = 32767

Comment: we can see 284MB swap used out of 31GB

Comment: any inputs jos...

Comment: Hmmmm, generally all looks good to me - at least for not too complicated queries. Do you have a lot of very complicated joins over more tables or very complicated queries with a lot of sorts or hash joins or group by aggregations? I know this is not easy to answer but if so then every session will take multiple "work_mem" segments...

Comment: Another thing - I presume this is a dedicated PostgreSQL database server and nothing else (beside for example monitoring) is running on it...

Comment: Thanks for inputs jos, we have queries with group by but we are not getting out of memory for those queries and we have dedicated server for postgreSQL DB .

Comment: Sounds like you are getting these errors only for some types of queries?

Comment: Yes Jos, sometimes we were getting this error where the query returning 1 row, and it is not that we dont have memory during that time, we know some 600M-1.5GB free mem available, appreciate any suggestion in this case

Comment: Well I know from our monitoring that there can be big spikes in memory usage but they are too short and very often are not visible in graphs because of too big scrape interval or using rate etc. But another question - does this error crashes whole PG server or "just" prevents to open new session? If whole server crashes (= is killed by OOM killer and restarts itself) could you search /var/log/syslog to see messages from OOM killer? They contain info about killed process with its memory usage + info about other running processes. Maybe you could see more here....

Comment: Thanks for the update Jos, good part is PG server is not crashing but due to out of memory some of our application processes are getting failed since they are not getting new session.

Comment: If PG is not crushing that's very good. Maybe there is another way around. We had similar problem with sessions not being opened due to "out of memory" and generally we could not do anything about it because there simply were some peaks during the day when server was overloaded. Therefore we installed pgbouncer and set pool_mode to "transaction". Since this change problems are gone. Because connections are now handled in much efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of limitations on the postgres user.
Check the output of 'ulimit -a' from postgres.

Set to unlimited (at least for files/open files/max processes), if not already.

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your suggestion.
we have verfied all these setting and all are fine.

is there any other area that we need to verify.